# Excel find differences between columns A and B and populate it in Column C

Tags: excel

This is my Sheet 1 Column A:

```
MemberId
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

This is in Sheet 2 column A:

```
MemberId
1
3
4
5
6
7
10
```

And I need Sheet 3, column A populated with

```
Missing MemberIds
2
8
9
```

That is the MemberId values that are missing in Sheet 2

Comment: This has already been answered on [Super User](http://superuser.com/q/430854/1170).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula. I shown it in single sheet. You can deploy it in 3 different sheet.

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10,0)),"",$A$1:$A$10),ROW()),"")
```

[image]

Note: This is an array formula. Press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after typing formula.